# How to use unity debugger in vscode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

[image]

This is the current debugger I'm using in vscode. How can I change this to the unity debugger that I downloaded? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Very oddly (as per usual Unity tech...) The official debugger is not being maintained and has been flagged by VSCode as 'Deprecated' (see: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/vscode-unity-debug/issues/206)

First off, since you did what I did and tried another debugger (as per your screenshot) you'll need to delete the Launch.json that created (it's in the root of your Project in the .vscode folder)

Now search for Unity Debugger in VSCode's Extensions. The official one is greyed out and shows as crossed out. I first tried that one but it didn't seem to work. 'Unity' wasn't shown in the list of available debuggers. (even after a VSCode restart). You could try it if you want, you might have better luck.

Instead, I then used an unofficial one by 'deitry' which shows as 'in Preview' (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deitry.unity-debug)

That worked great for me. When you then go into the Debug tab, 'Unity Editor' now shows as an option. Debugging (breakpoints, stacktrace etc.) all seems to work

Comment: If Visual Studio weren't so clunky I'd use it instead. In the meantime I'm glad there's a VS Code debugger that still works.